# More Golden ratio - Link to $x^2 - y^2 =xy $

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, recreational-mathematics, golden-ratio

So, I like to mess around on Desmos. And there I am, looking at my all old graphs and I came across this one ($x^2-y^2=xy$) :

[image]

And now that I know calculus (this was when I was $11$), I got all interested in that gradient (I will focus on the line in the first quadrant). And since it looked linear, I checked if it intersected at any integer values (to make finding the gradient easier)

And guess what. The line almost perfectly intersected at consecutive Fibonacci number values for $x$ and $y$. For example:

When $x=8, y \approx 5$

$x=21, y \approx 13$

$x=55, y \approx 34$

(Try some for yourself)

This leads me to make the assumption $y =\frac{x}{\phi}$, hence the gradient is $\frac{1}{\phi}$.

However, working out the derivative (through implicit differentiation) gives me a different answer:

$x^2-y^2=xy$

$2xdx-2ydy=xdy+ydx$

$2xdx-ydx=xdy-2ydy$

$dx(2x-y)=dy(x-2y)$

$\frac{2x-y}{x-2y}=\frac{dy}{dx}$

This is not the answer of phi that I was expecting - What's going on, can I extract the goden ratio out of this, and what link is there between the golden ratio and the graph?

Comment: As a rule, you don't need calculus for quadratics. But this has what you may find an interesting connection to the Fibonacci sequence. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Relation_to_the_golden_ratio) & [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#Relationship_to_Fibonacci_sequence).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for calculus. One can rewrite the original equation as $$x^2-xy-y^2=(x-\varphi y)\left(x+\frac{y}{\varphi}\right)=0.$$ Therefore, the graph is just the union of the lines with slopes $\frac{1}{\varphi}$ and $-\varphi$ through the origin.

Comment: Thank you very much - I guess I overcomplicated it. But then why isn't the derivative negative phi or 1 over phi?

Comment: @JakubSkop It is, but you'll probably need to substitute your original equation in your expression to prove so. That should prove to be somewhat time consuming, but should eventually lead to the same answer.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll see what I can do to it.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$
x^2 - y^2 = xy \Longrightarrow \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2 +\frac{y}{x} -1 = 0\Longrightarrow \frac{y}{x}= \frac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2} = \frac{1}{\phi}\lor-\phi.
$$
So the slopes of the lines are indeed the golden ratio and its inverse.

Answer (score 1):

For each fixed $x$, you can solve the equation for $y$ giving
$$
y=-\varphi x \vee y=\frac1\varphi x
$$

Comment: I don't entirely understand what you did there - Can you explain?